# Start mongo failed

Tags: mongodb

I get an error when I try to start mongo using the "mongod" command (on Macintosh).

```
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

My logs :

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.783 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=859 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-de-Anthony
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.784 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.4
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.784 [initandlisten] git version: 4ec1fb96702c9d4c57b1e06dd34eb73a16e407d2
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.784 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.784 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.784 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.784 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.784 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:28017
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] now exiting
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 dbexit: 
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.802 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.802 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.802 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.802 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.803 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.803 dbexit: really exiting now
```

UPDATE:

When I execute the "mongo" command :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Anthony:Sites anthonycluse$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
Tue Oct 29 11:43:15 [initandlisten] 
Tue Oct 29 11:43:15 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
> show dbs;
anthonycluse    (empty)
local   (empty)
>
```

It means that the username is "test" no?

UPDATE 2 :

The "show users;" command :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Anthony:Sites anthonycluse$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.4
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
Tue Oct 29 11:43:15 [initandlisten] 
Tue Oct 29 11:43:15 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
> show users;
>
```

Comment: both needed ports (27017, 28017) seem to already be in use. Are you sure the service is not already started?

Comment: Nope - test is the name of the default database.

Comment: Is there a command to show the current username? This is my computer... In local...

Comment: Hmm... the [show users](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) command might shed some light on the situation.. Personally I've never used authentication with mongo, so I'm not 100% sure...

Comment: See update 2, it seems that I don't have any users...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in side the log file:

```
Tue Oct 29 13:15:48.801 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:28017
```

Specifically this part: `"Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:28017"`

It seems that there is already a mongo instance running on that default port 27017. It might not even be a mongo instance but some other application that is using that port.

Comment: Ok but where can I see my username and password ? (of localhost)

Comment: um...huh? What username and password? For mongo?

Comment: I don't think that mongo has a default username and password. You actually have to enable authentication to have these features. Did you set one during installation?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't remember... And I need them.

Comment: Well... How can you prove to us that your are the admin of the system then? :-P in sorry, but I won't be able to help you hack into a database :-)

Comment: I guess this will be a lesson of password management... Don't worry, it'll only happen once... From now on you'll remember.

Comment: I don't want to hack a database, I just want to connect my Mongo database with Geddy (node js framework). But I don't remember the username and password... I installed Genghis to manage my Mongo database and it works, I can create and edit a database, but with my NodeJS App it doesn't work because I don't have the username and password...

Answer (score 3):

Is there another process listening on those ports? Try finding out with:

```
netstat -tulpen | grep 017 # 017 for both port 27017 and 28017
```

Kill that process if you're sure you don't need it. As answered below by Lix, there may already be a mongo process running.

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs it is clear that there is another mongodb instance running on default, i believe you installed mongodb using rpm and started this service using service mongodb start. so when the server restarts by default it starts some of the services, using defaultconfiguration which will be avialble in /etc/mongod.config edit this file or stop the one which is running already so you can avoid the mongod default instamce and made ur version to up and running